# Ao usar puts sai somente o endereço, e não a mensagem esperada

Tags: ruby

Olá, estou iniciando com a linguagem ruby e encontro o seguinte problema que é na hora de printar mensagem através do to_s:

classe principal

```
require File.expand_path("lib/Livro")

biblioteca = []

instancia = Livro.new "Ruby", "X", "Casa do Código", 56.40
instancia_dois = Livro.new "Java", "Y", "Casa do Código", 78.9

biblioteca << instancia
biblioteca << instancia_dois

puts biblioteca
```

classe acessada

```
class Livro

    attr_accessor :preco,:autor,:editora,:nome

    def initialize nome_livro, autor,_editora = nil, preco
      @nome = nome_livro
      @autor = autor
      @editora = editora
      @preco = preco    
    end

    def to_s
      "Autor: #{@nome}, Autor: #{@autor}, Editora: #{@editora},Preço: #{@preco}"
    end
end
```

Na saída do código ao invés da mensagem anexada em to_s aparece apenas os endereços dos objetos, tentei procurar na internet mas n achei nada que podesse ajudar obrigado desde já.

Comment: Faça assim biblioteca.map(&:to_s) Como está começando vou te dar uma dica, acessa o style guide do Ruby para ir aprendendo a formatar o código com alguns padrões. Abraço.

Comment: Que bom que minha resposta lhe foi útil! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá rodei seu código aqui e funcionou:

Instanciando a classe

```
class Livro

 attr_accessor :preco,:autor,:editora,:nome    

 def initialize nome_livro, autor,_editora = nil, preco    
   @nome = nome_livro      
   @autor = autor      
   @editora = editora      
   @preco = preco          
 end      

 def to_s    
   "Autor: #{@nome}, Autor: #{@autor}, Editora: #{@editora},Preço: #{@preco}"      
 end      
end
```

E rodando os testes:

```
biblioteca = []

instancia = Livro.new "Ruby", "X", "Casa do Código", 56.40
=> #<Livro:0x00000001f18aa0 @autor="X", @editora=nil, @nome="Ruby", @preco=56.4>
instancia_dois = Livro.new "Java", "Y", "Casa do Código", 78.9
=> #<Livro:0x00000001e71688 @autor="Y", @editora=nil, @nome="Java", @preco=78.9>

biblioteca << instancia
=> [#<Livro:0x00000001f18aa0 @autor="X", @editora=nil, @nome="Ruby", @preco=56.4>]
biblioteca << instancia_dois
=> [#<Livro:0x00000001f18aa0 @autor="X", @editora=nil, @nome="Ruby", @preco=56.4>, #<Livro:0x00000001e71688 @autor="Y", @editora=nil, @nome="Java", @preco=78.9>]

puts biblioteca
Autor: Ruby, Autor: X, Editora: ,Preço: 56.4
Autor: Java, Autor: Y, Editora: ,Preço: 78.9
```

Executei tudo diretamente no console.